# load the div ng-click

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have the div section which is used to show the form in reply comment

```
 <div class="box-body showmycomments"></div>
 <div class="box-footer showmycomments"></div>
```

I have reply comment anchor tag in another div

```
<a ng-click="add(data)" style="cursor:pointer;" > Reply Comments</a>
```

Now I want to load 'showmycomments' div for each and every reply comment on ng-click.

My module has multiple comments with reply comment option which is in `ng-repeat` I need to load the div 'showmycomment' for each and every replay comment. 
comment is displayed as shown in image.If i click Show comments as it show the form as shown in 2nd image.I want to load the form bellow reply comment if I click the anchor tag.

[image]

image 2

[image]

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. Can you please rephrase it?

Comment: @ Shashank Agrawal please check my updated question

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion your approach is wrong.

Instead of creating a div and duplicating it (possible though messy), you should use `ng-include` to inject a whole html wherever you need.

This would look like this:

**index.html** (or the html you have the `ng-repeat` on

```
<div ng-repeat="comment in comments">
    <div ng-include="'comment.html'"></div>
</div>
```

**comment.html** - here you can use the `comment` from above.

```
<div class="comment-container">
     {{ comment.text }}
</div>
```

So for every item, you duplicate the `comment.html` and fill it with whatever you want.

Comment: can you plz guide me to do it